# Convert Json to List of Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I am calling an API using:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);

String content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The returned `content` is the following Json:

```
{
  "sensors": [ 
   { "value": "1.2", "valid": "true" },
   { "value": "1.1", "valid": "false" },
   { "value": "1.7", "valid": "true" }
  ]
}
```

I need, for example, to sum the values of all sensors with `valid` equal to `true`.

Can I convert `content` to a list of objects and query it without defining a class for the type?

Comment: Yes. But why don't you want to define a class? What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @mason It is just temporary testing code and I was wondering if that is possible in an easy way

Comment: You've changed the value of content. It should go without being said, but you need to accurately describe what you're working with. Does the "valid" property really contain string values in the JSON? Or does it contain boolean values?

Comment: I don't know what could possibly be more easy than creating a class to represent the response structure, deserialize to an instance of that class, then use Linq to filter the objects. There's other ways of going about this of course. But you included an arbitrary requirement not to use classes, and that's just going to make things more difficult.

Comment: It is possible but using classes would easier and more readable.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid creating a class becuase "it takes time to do so". Try searching for "json to c# class" in your favourite search engine

Comment: This may be a really inane suggestion, but something that's debatably easier than creating a class is creating a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for really dirty piece of code that "does that exactly" then here it is:

```
// use package System.Text.Json
var sum = JsonObject.Parse(json)["sensors"]
        .AsArray().OfType<JsonObject>()
        .Where(x => x["valid"].GetValue<string>() == "true")
        .Sum(x => double.Parse(x["value"].GetValue<string>()));
```

But if you plan to work more on this code you are working on, please listen to other comments that suggest creating a C# class for `Sensors` and another for `SensorValue` and simply deserialize it.

From the shape of JSON, it does not seems that there will be tons of data OR that performance is critical. Then deserializing JSON to some classes and processing those objects without craziness of plain JSON structures makes more sense.